# Is there a single noun that describes "need not"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There are four types of deontic modality, which can be expressed by the following modal expressions:

1. Can
2. Need not
3. Must not
4. Must

Out of these, 1, 3, and 4 respectively corresponds to the following nouns:

1. Permission
2. ???
3. Prohibition
4. Obligation

Is there a simple word that corresponds to type 2?

Comment: There are actually many more than four types of deontic modality. Every modal auxiliary has at least one, and sometimes more than one deontic sense (_can_ can mean deontic permission or deontic ability). As for the deontic sense of _need not_, it means Not (Necessary p), just like _don't need to_ or _don't have to_, and 
there doesn't appear to be a neat English term to refer to that logical situation. There often isn't; that's why *Deontic* gets used.

Comment: *Can* expresses *ability*, doesn't it? For *permission*, the verb is *may*.

Comment: If you prefer. Of course, preferences differ, and usages even more so.

Comment: Suggestion? Information?

Comment: Aren't Can and Need Not the same? Or do you mean Should vs Should Not

Comment: @MikeBrown I agree with you.

Comment: Not *the* @JohnMLawler? (Checks your /users/ page....) Oh, my! Very nice to see you here!

Comment: @msh210: Don't talk John up too much! We need to get him to talk *down* to our level so we can understand what he tells us! (seriously, John, we are honoured). Like when I found I was rubbing shoulders with some of the world's greatest crossword setters at [fifteen squared](http://fifteensquared.net/category/guardian/)

Comment: Gimme a break, please. Sometimes somebody asks a question that links straight to a course, or a section of a course, or something I put on [alt.usage.english](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue.html) a long time ago. I think I like the format here pretty well, but I'm always happy to get feedback on being clear and useful. That's the job, after all.

Comment: What is the difference between `must not` and `need not`?

Comment: @ErickRobertson: Plenty, I am sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Remission* has a sense of *exemption* from doing something. So either of the two could serve the purpose.

Comment: Awesome. That is the word I was looking for. Remission was not in my vocabulary, but yes, I know the word exemption, and I think that is the perfect fit.

Comment: Remission in this sense is typically found only in legalese. We also see some occurrences in administration documents in the corporate and academic fields. I do not know if it is used as such in general literature or speech, though.

Comment: Can I expect a comment about the down vote, please?

Comment: -1: I wasn't the original downvoter, but [remission](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/remission) doesn't mean [exemption](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exempt) in any normal context. And as @John comments to OP, there are many "shades" of deontic modality - to me, *exemption* largely steps outside the entire continuum, rather than indicating the degree to which something "ought to be true".

Comment: No, but Kris is correct that "remiss" and "remit" do not, in ordinary (or even non-legal formal) usage mean "need not". I don't know about legal usage.

Comment: @Ryan: *Remission* has several different meanings, but I think the main difference between the legal and medical usage is largely to do with "permanence". A legal remission is a "once and for all" setting aside of a burdensome obligation. But if you're *in remission* medically speaking, the implication is that your problem is actually expected to come back.

Comment: OP thinks *exemption* serves the purpose.

Answer (score 18):

[Optionality](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/optionality) - noun form for the quality of being *Left to choice; not compulsory or automatic.*

Apparently this word has become [significantly more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optionality&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) over the past 50 years.

Comment: Chris's answer turned out to be even better to me. Yours is still next best.

Comment: Yeah, and to keep the endings the same (which is nice), use *option*.

Comment: @Ryan: Per my comment to Terry's answer, I think *option* and *election* would look a bit odd alongside OP's other nouns, because they're both firmly established in somewhat different usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that *election* doesn't fit. It has a range of meanings with a shared underlying connection, but its common usage is so strong that to mean it as *option* is foolish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *Option*, on the other hand, strikes me as particularly good. The items of a well-formed list should be the same part of speech, at least, so that each item fulfills the same grammatical role. *Option* satisfies that requirement, and also has the benefit having the same ending, so there is a certain assonance. Finally, it expresses perfectly something that you may, not need not do. "There is permission to sing. There is the option to sing. There is a prohibition on singing. The is an obligation to sing." Perfect!

Comment: @Ryan: Hmm. *The wording of this notice implies* **permission**. Which you can happily replace with **prohibition, obligation,** or even **optionality**. But I don't feel comfortable with *The wording of this notice implies* **option**.

Answer (score 13):

**[Unnecessity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unnecessity)** would fit the bill, if only it weren't obsolete.  However, **[needlessness](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/needlessness)** is not obsolete.  To avoid the contrived aura, you may desire to go for a longer phrase and just use *absence of necessity* or *lack of necessity*.  Or, consider using a positive-oriented word: *optionality*.

I gave [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51112/10041) an upvote on **optionality** and wanted to point out that it is not only significantly more common than it was fifty years ago, it has even become [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optionality,needlessness,lack%20of%20necessity,unnecessity&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than any of the other options:

[image]

On that basis, I think *optionality* deserves the cake on this issue.

Comment: It is actually 'absence of necessity', and I am wondering if there is a single word to express that.

Comment: Unless you allow 'needlessness'.

Comment: Needlessness seems to be a good choice after optionality.

Comment: 'non-necessity' seems fine to me.

Comment: Wondering: Does _needlessness_ convey a negative overtone like _superfluousness_ ?

Answer (score 4):

When **need** is used in the positive form it signifies **necessity**. In the negative form it signifies **lack of necessity**.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to say that in a single word. It looks like optionality or needlessness would give that meaning.

Comment: @sawa: I agree. I gave you the term used in grammar books. But I think you chose the correct answer wisely.

Answer (score 4):

What about [elective](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elective)?

> Elective: not compulsory; optional ; possible but not necessary; left
>   to personal choice

You need to take this course = You are required to take this course (required course)

You needn't take this course = This course is elective to you (elective course)

Comment: The big problem with this one is when you want a noun form for *the quality of being concerned with elective matters*. I was a bit iffy about putting up *optionality*, but it's positively commonplace by comparison with [electivity](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electivity%2Coptionality&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Elective could be a noun form itself as in "free electives". What do you think of it?

Comment: Yes, I do think it's reasonable to "force" these adjectives into noun roles (you could do the same with *optional*). It's just they seem a bit out of place when the other three in the list are "natural" nouns formed using the *-tion* suffix, which we can't do with either of our offerings. Well, you could have *election*, I suppose, but standard usage for that word makes it a bit awkward. I certainly couldn't get away with *option*! :)

Answer (score 0):

Other synonyms to consider:

- noncompulsory
- nonobligatory / nonobligational
- discretionary / discretional
- voluntary